# Android devices without google play services

Tags: android

There are any android device without `google play services`?

It looks like amazon phones dont have google play on them.

I want to use features like places and billing but I'm afraid of a phone without it, how can I be sure about that? how can I validate this programmatically?

Comment: you can check weather the google play services has been installed on the device. if yes proceed with your app, else do something appropriate.

Comment: Yes there are devices without google play services. ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191875/google-play-services-how-to-handle-devices-that-do-not-have-google-play

Comment: I'm asking if there are a device without it, it's a different question.

Comment: If you only plan on releasing your app on Google Play, then you can assume your users will have Google Play Services. If you're developing for Amazon or something, then that's a different case.

Comment: mh... wether you should reformulate your question or the @Mathias F. answer is pretty correct. By the way, older devices won´t support play services, I´ve got an HTC Magic working and it´s not Play capable

Comment: HTC Magic have which android version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> There are any android device without google play services?

There are an estimated tens of millions of Kindle Fire and Fire TV devices, none of which have the Google proprietary apps or the Play Services Framework.

There are millions of BlackBerry 10 devices, which can run Android apps on top of the BB10 OS, none of which have the Google proprietary apps or the Play Services Framework.

There are countless devices shipping in various markets (e.g., China) by smaller manufacturers that elect to eschew Google's proprietary apps or the Play Services Framework.

However, as Eric S. notes in the comments, if you are distributing through the Play Store, you will not reach these devices, as they do not have the Play Store on them (outside of people installing pirated copies of the Play Store APK).

Comment: Installing Play Store from an APK doesn't make it pirated (Play Store is free). There's patched versions of Play Store which don't require Google Play Services to work. This is mostly done on rooted phones out of privacy concerns. There's also FOSS stores like Aurora Store which provide access to apks distributed by Play Store on phones without play services.

I'd suggest distributing your app through G-Droid as well as Play Store to reach a wider user base (as it's free). Whether you care about supporting phones without play services is entirely up to you as a developer though.