# How to handle Google API Client if not having updated Google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I am using fused location Google api client to get location,as I am having update device so it is working fine, there may be scenario like customer may not having updated google play services. so what minimum google play services version is required for Fused location(Google API Client), and how to check or validate that programmatically.

Comment: please visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/34943703/4853552 for the "how to check "

Comment: what minimum google play services version is required for Fused location(Google API Client). api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);

Comment: A complete example of handling Google API Client, [AbstractGoogleApiClientActivity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Location/FusedNew/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/weather2/AbstractGoogleApiClientActivity.java)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any minimum version is mentioned in the Android Documents https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

But if you want to handle Errors while connecting to the GoogleApiClient you should implement GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

And call this code by passing error result code and implement onActivityResult to handle the result:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment(resultCode,this,CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
```

Note: I haven't implemented it, but that is how it is done.